# multiple RewriteCond base on query strings with the same page same parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET)\/site\/oldpage\.asp/\?id=(.*)&tid=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^/newfolder/main/newpage-%2/#post-%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET)\/site\/oldpage\.asp/\?id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^/newfolder/main/newpage-%1/? [L,R=301]


`http://olddomain.com/site/oldpage.asp?id=32`
`http://olddomain.com/site/oldpage?id=677&tid=32`
```

The result works only on first parameter and redirect me to

**My goal is to get this Urls:**

if only **id** then
`http://olddomain.com/main/newpage-32/`

if **id** and **tid** then
`http://olddomain.com/main/newpage-32/#post-677`

**without any querystring**

what I getting now is :

both **id** and **tid** the results are
`http://olddomain.com/main/newpage-677/?id=677&tid=32`

if i send only **id** I get
`http://olddomain.com/main/newpage-32/?id=32` works but with the query string at the end

Any idea how to solve it?